# Using UIScrollView with UIVisualEffectView (UIBlurEffect) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiblureffect

I'm using `UIBlurEffect` from `UIVisualEffectView` to produce the look introduced in iOS 7. To do so I programmatically add anything I want portrayed on top of the blur to the `contentView`, as described in the `UIBlurEffect` Class Reference:

> A `UIBlurEffect` object applies a blurring effect to the content layered
>   behind a `UIVisualEffectView`. Views added to the `contentView` of a
>   `UIVisualEffectView` are not affected by the blur effect.

But now I need to add a `UIScrollView` into the mix, and the fact that I had to use the `contentView` has left me completely confused. I'm not very familiar with the `UIScrollView`, but the **iOS 8 Swift Programming Cookbook** gives this example:

[image]

I'm not in need of displaying an `imageView`, but instead a separate `view` with many views inside of it in the hierarchy. Where exactly do I add the `scrollView`? Do I set `scrollView` as a `subview` of `contentView`? Or the other way around, the `contentView` as a `subview` of `scrollView`? Here's my current code:

```
class InfoVC: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // blur
        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light))
        blur.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(blur)
        blur.contentView.addSubview(self.contentView)

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to scroll something on top of the blur effect, correct?

In that case you need to add the scroll view to the content view of the blur view.
Assuming the `contentView` is the view you want to scroll it should work like this:

```
let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)) 
blur.frame = view.bounds
view.addSubview(blur)
UIScrollView scrollView = UIScrollView(frame:blur.bounds)
blur.contentView.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
scrollView.contentSize = contentView.frame.size // or whatever other size you like
```